# Is there a way to limit API calls for the individual users

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am working on a FLASK App for a client and he wants to limit the Routes for the individual users (without login or authentication tho). So for example a user has 4 calls available and can use all of them on that day, another one has 4 calls as well so he can also use them on the same day.
Is there a way to do that without the information of who the user is, nor storing any information about the user in database?

I found something similar thats already build in in FLASK it self but thats just a Limitation for the route itself, so the route has 100 calls avaible a day and thats it.

Answer (score 1):

The more effective way of achieving this is probably to authenticate your user, but it seems you want to avoid that.

You also can try to identify the user, for example with the IP address, but you should be very careful as this can have side effects, like assuming two different users are the same because they share their IP address.

Third way, you can use something like a cookie to store the number of calls already used, on client side. However, the user can easily change or delete the cookie.